# Error 'Google_Service_Drive_ChildReference' not found

Tags: php, google-api, yii2, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to use Google Drive and Google Cloud Storage, but I got the error:

> Class 'Google_Service_Drive_ChildReference' not found'

Here's my code

```
$ref = new \Google_Service_Drive_ChildReference();
$ref->setId($createdFile->getId());
$drive->children->insert($view->drive_folder, $ref);
```

Anyone have any idea of how to fix this problem? I tried all i could but doesn't work. Also note i am using Yii2 Framework with PHP 7.3.0

This is what i have in my composer.json

```
"google/apiclient": "^2.2"
```

Comment: which service APi are you referencing to? google drive does not have any namespace with that name that is why you are getting that error where did you get that code from?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert

Answer (score 2):

You need to look [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/migration) which tells you that this class was changed to `Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile` since `1.0.0` version so you can change the above code to

```
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$result = $service->files->insert($file, array(
  'data' => file_get_contents(TESTFILE),
  'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
  'uploadType' => 'media'
));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not work, I have already tried, this is for v2, v3 has different flow :(

Comment: @Gabriel , well that's odd how have you modified the code, can you share in the question by editing and what error are you getting, you need to init the `$service` in the above code before you use it